# Update accept rate upon asking a question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, accept-rate

Wouldn't it be benificial to immediately update the accept rate of a user when he asks a question? This allows him to first accept answers to improve his accept rate, and then ask a question, showing the latest accept rate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about another approach?  The way we do this now, there's no reason we can't recalculate your rate **when you accept or unaccept an answer**, *immediately*.  In the next build, this will start happening.

---

*A bit further explanation:*

When it comes to accept rate, *asking* a question has no *immediate* effect, since questions must meet a few criteria to be considered:

- At least one answer
- **At least 3 days old**
- Not closed
- Not deleted
- Not community wiki

The second one is huge here because a new question (unless asking rapidly, before the job runs daily) has no effect on your accept rate, not for 3 days (so it has time to get some answers).

Comment: Haha, I wasn't thinking straight, just was posting questions and was sad to see I had a low accept rate. :) Ofcourse, that's a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Accepting several answers in a short period should also trigger an update.